# wordpress появляются подзаголовки в меню

Tags: wordpress

Создаю меню

`footer.php`

```
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'footer_menu',
            'menu' => 'Меню в подвале',
            'menu_class' => 'footer__menu',
        ));
        ?>
```

`fuctions.php`

```
register_nav_menu('footer_menu','Footer menu');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На активной странице в соответствующем пункте меню появился подзаголовок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как его убрать?

Comment: А не заполнять не пробовал? :)

Comment: Что не заполнять? Подзаголовки? зачем я тогда их добавлял!

Comment: Так и я о том - зачем заполнял если хочешь удалить?

Comment: @SeVlad я тебе в slack написал ))

Comment: @KAGGDesign наверное не мне. Я ничего не получал.:( Подключайся к каналу ВП https://ruwp.slack.com.

Comment: @SeVlad я в wordpress.slack.com писал. А на ruwp.slack.com приглашение наверное нужно?

Comment: @KAGGDesign да нет вроде.